# SonarQube 4.5 does not populate technical debt with mysql datasource

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I mvn sonar:sonar a project and problems with our code is recorded in the technical debt in sonarqube when we use the default database - i.e. default install of version 4.5. It works, out of the box:

Blocker    0
 Critical   0
 Major  88
 Minor  70
 Info   12

I change the datasource to mysql and

Blocker    0
 Critical   0
 Major  0
 Minor  0
 Info   0

is recorded. No errors presented by mvn or sonar. I can see all drivers load during mvn run.

In .m2/settings.xml I have

```
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.jdbc.url>
              jdbc:mysql://sonar.company.io:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
            </sonar.jdbc.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>pass</sonar.jdbc.password>
            <sonar.host.url>
              http://sonar.company.io:9000
            </sonar.host.url>
            <sonar.verbose>true</sonar.verbose>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

I can am able to connect via the hostname using mysql -usonar -ppass -h sonar.company.io and there is content in the database.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| sonar              |

mysql> show table status;
+---------------------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                      | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+---------------------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------+
| action_plans              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |   4194304 |              1 | 2014-09-30 14:30:17 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_bin  |     NULL |                |         |
| active_dashboards         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     5 |           3276 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |   4194304 |              6 | 2014-09-30 14:30:10 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_bin  |     NULL |                |         |
| active_rule_parameters    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    42 |            390 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |   4194304 |             43 | 2014-09-30 14:30:16 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_bin  |     NULL |                |         |
| active_rules              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |  1099 |             74 |       81920 |               0 |        49152 |   4194304 |            992 | 2014-09-30 14:30:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_bin  |     NULL |                |         |
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe your project is associated to a quality profile on which no rule is activated?

Comment: That does not explain why changing the data source makes a difference. It should not matter.

Comment: If you change the data source, you change the DB you're referring to, so this can change everything because the quality profiles are defined in the DB, the association with projects too, ... and so on.

Comment: It's a fresh install. Both experiments are against a blank data source with the exception that we created the sonar database in MySQL.

Comment: OK, then I don't see where the problem can come from... I've just tried on my box with SQ 4.5, Java 7, MySql 5.7 and everything's working perfectly.

Comment: Do you have just one database in mysql called 'sonar' ?